# Get single node value inside a node in PLSQL

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

Here is a xml :

```
<root>
  <error>
     <description>
       <code>I899</code>
     </description>
     <solution>
       <code>AZE4</code>
     </solution>
  </error>
  <error>
     <description>
       <code>I900</code>
     </description>
  </error>
</root>
```

Here is the code:

```
myParser := DBMS_XMLPARSER.newParser;
ficContent := DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.Read2Clob(directoryPasrau, crmNomfilename , '0');
DBMS_XMLPARSER.parseBuffer(myParser,ficContent);
dom := DBMS_XMLPARSER.getDocument(myParser);
rootElement := DBMS_XMLDOM.getDocumentElement(dom);

nlErrors := DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.selectNodes(DBMS_XMLDOM.makeNode(dom), '//' || rootName || '/error', 'xmlns:ns2="http://www.gip-mds.fr/"');
```

Till here it is fine I get the 2 error nodes

```
FOR i IN 0 .. DBMS_XMLDOM.getLength(nlErrors) - 1 LOOP
  tabBisInfosList.EXTEND;
  tabBisInfosList(i+1).descriptionCode := TRIM(TRANSLATE(TRANSLATE(DBMS_XMLDOM.getNodeValue(DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.selectSingleNode(DBMS_XMLDOM.Item(nlAnomalies, i), 'description/code')), chr(10), ' '), chr(9), ' '));
END LOOP;
```

There is nothing in tabBisInfosList(i+1).descriptionCode.

Same if I use those patterns :
 '/description/code' or '//description/code'

Do you know why ?

Ty

Answer (score 0):

Two errors here :

1. the xpath expression should be this one : './description/code'
2. It is not :

TRIM(TRANSLATE(TRANSLATE(DBMS_XMLDOM.getNodeValue(DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.selectSingleNode(DBMS_XMLDOM.Item(nlAnomalies, i), 'description/code')), chr(10), ' '), chr(9), ' '));

But

TRIM(TRANSLATE(TRANSLATE(DBMS_XMLDOM.getNodeValue(DBMS_XMLDOM.getFirstChild(DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.selectSingleNode(DBMS_XMLDOM.Item(nlAnomalies, i), 'description/code'))), chr(10), ' '), chr(9), ' '));